# Boot from CD using UEFI instead of BIOS

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, bios, uefi

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad Y510P. This is my last attempt at recovering my computer, as my recovery partitions are gone and I cannot boot into my computer otherwise. I have Windows 8 x64 OEM installed. I am trying to use a previously created system image on an external hard drive to restore my laptop.

I have two boot options in BIOS: either Legacy (which has the boot from CD option) or UEFI (which doesn't have that option). When I fire up a recovery disk (in Legacy) and try to start the system image restore, I get the following error:

```
Windows cannot restore a system image to a computer that has different firmware. The system image was created on a computer using EFI and this computer is using BIOS.
```

The following link shows how to boot into the UEFI shell, but I can't do it because I get a "no such interface supported" error:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/55742bfc-3392-485a-9ce1-204b3b55050f/system-image-restore-fails-because-of-efibios?forum=windowsbackup

Is there *anything* I can do here to attempt to use the previously mentioned image?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I recently struggled with UEFI boot on a Lenovo IdeaTab too, but this is just a shot in the dark: Did ypu disable *Secure Boot*? On my IdeaTab Lynx I had to set a user password first, before the Secure Boot option was visible. Only after these two steps I was able to boot from CD. This was so ridiculous

Comment: @nixda I disabled Secure Boot. Because the partitions are missing, I cannot boot into windows. My last resort is to fresh install another copy of windows...

Comment: I have had related problems on a Lenovo G580 after installing Ubuntu: all my partitions (including recovery) are still present, but all attempts to boot or recover give UEFI errors. My solution is to run Windows in a VM, which may be an alternative option for you.

Comment: @AFH I already installed a fresh copy of windows, but thanks for the heads up!